# Gluon Reflection list external jnativehook file GlobalScreen ( I have issue )

Tags: maven, javafx, reflection, gluon

I'm Still learning about gluon How it's works I'm a student.
now the problem is it's not running after the client:build before it's working perfectly.

so here is the problem. I have added GlobalScreen class in reflection but it's a method or something I don't understand giving me an issue so how to solve it please guide me.

```
      [Sun Jan 31 22:19:45 PKT 2021][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK ====================
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Hello There
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GG1
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GG2
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Jan 31, 2021 10:19:46 PM org.jnativehook.DefaultLibraryLocator getLibraries
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] SEVERE: Unable to extract the native library /org/jnativehook/lib/windows/x86_64/JNativeHook.dll!
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Exception in Application start method
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:519)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.getAutoRepeatRate()Ljava/lang/Integer; [symbol: Java_org_jnativehook_GlobalScreen_getAutoRepeatRate or Java_org_jnativehook_GlobalScreen_getAutoRepeatRate__]
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage.getOrFindEntryPoint(JNINativeLinkage.java:153)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.nativeCallAddress(JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.java:57)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.getAutoRepeatRate(Unknown Source)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:351)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:271)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at sample.Main.start(Main.java:34)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:102)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    [Sun Jan 31 22:19:46 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      ... 3 more
                 _______  ___      __   __  _______  __    _
                |       ||   |    |  | |  ||       ||  |  | |
                |    ___||   |    |  | |  ||   _   ||   |_| |
                |   | __ |   |    |  |_|  ||  | |  ||       |
                |   ||  ||   |___ |       ||  |_|  ||  _    |
                |   |_| ||       ||       ||       || | |   |
                |_______||_______||_______||_______||_|  |__|
    
        Access to the latest docs, tips and tricks and more info on
        how to get support? Register your usage of Gluon Substrate now at
    
        https://gluonhq.com/activate
    
    
    
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  6.452 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-31T22:19:49+05:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>GameCheats</groupId>
    <artifactId>InvokerBotKey</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>InvokerBotKeys</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <mainClassName>sample.Launcher</mainClassName>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.1stleg/jnativehook -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.35</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${client.target}</target>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>sample.Controller</list>
                        <list>sample.Main</list>
                        <list>sample.HotKeys</list>
                        <list>sample.Invoker</list>
                        <list>sample.GlobalKeyListener</list>
                        <list>javafx.application.Application</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.Parent</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.Scene</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.robot.Robot</list>
                        <list>javafx.stage.Stage</list>
                        <list>javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.input.KeyCode</list>
                        <list>java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit</list>
                        <list>javafx.event.ActionEvent</list>
                        <list>javafx.fxml.FXML</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.TextField</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton</list>
                        <list>javafx.application.Platform</list>
                        <list>org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen</list>
                        <list>org.jnativehook.NativeHookException</list>
                        <list>org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent</list>
                        <list>org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener</list>
                        <list>org.jnativehook.DefaultLibraryLocator</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>
                http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: The native dll library included in the JNativeHook jar is loaded from [resources](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/2.2/src/main/java/com/github/kwhat/jnativehook/DefaultLibraryLocator.java#L82), therefore you need to add it to the resources list `<resourcesList><list>.*\\.dll$</list></resourcesList>` in the plugin's configuration. See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_resourceslist. That should get you further...

Comment: can you please show me few examples like how to add jar files so in the future I can add any jar files and other related resources

Comment: All jars from dependencies are added via classpath. The problem might be in their content. If you want to add resources with given extensions, by default these are loaded: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_resourceslist, else you need to add them via `resourcesList`.

Comment: I added '<resourcesList><list>.*\\.dll$</list></resourcesList>' in the pom file. and now it's not showing any error just not running the application. I'm sorry to give you the trouble I'm not professional neither I have any instructor.

Comment: Process run until end failed with result: -1073741819

Comment: I tried on Mac, and it crashed on runtime, so I assume the same could happen on Windows too. It might require checking the classes used via reflection from the JNI code (those will go to the `jniList`).

Comment: can you show me examples of how to add-in jnilist